# Joomla 2.5 upload file dynamically

Tags: javascript, forms, joomla2.5

I'm converting a Joomla 1.5 component to J2.5  I upload files dynamically.  An iframe is filled with a form to do this, the iframe has an inner iframe to set the target of the form. After recieving the JSON answer, I use a function on the `onload` of the inner iframe to erase the iframe and display the uploaded image (using elements of the parent page).  Everything works great on J1.5, but on J2.5 I recieve a `joomla.json` file to download, and seems like the form is not using the target.

The function to display the form on the outter iframe is:

```
function showUploadImage(evt) {

    if (!document.getElementById("uploadIFrame")) {

        return false;

    }

    var frame = document.getElementById("uploadIFrame");

    var doc = frame.contentDocument;

    var page;

    page = "\

            <html> \

                <head> \

                    <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo JRoute::_(JURI::base().'/components/com_tutorial/css/base.css',false); ?>' type='text/css' /> \

                    <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo JRoute::_(JURI::base().'components/com_tutorial/css/upframe.css',false); ?>' type='text/css' /> \
                </head> \

                <body>";

    page += ' \

            <div id="waitimage"></div> \

            <form id="fileUploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_tutorial&view=edittutorial&task=savetutimage&tmpl=json&format=json&tutId='.$this->tutId); ?>" target="uploadTarget"> \

                <label class="title" for="images"><?php echo JText::_("UPLOAD IMAGE"); ?></label> \

                <div class="separator25"></div> \

                <div id="pageimages"> \

                    <div id="newimgfields"> \

                        <div class="controw"> \

                            <label class="title" for="image"><?php echo JText::_('SELECT_FILE'); ?></label><input size="35" id="image" type="file" name="image" /> \

                        </div> \

                        <div class="controw"> \

                            <input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById(\'waitimage\').innerHTML=\'<div class = &quot;mooloader&quot;></div>\';" value="<?php echo JText::_('UPLOAD_IMAGE'); ?>" /> \

                        </div> \

                    </div> \

                </div> \

            </form> \

            <iframe id="uploadTarget" name="uploadTarget" src=""  style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe> \

            ';

    page += "</body></html>";

    // now write out the new contents

    if (doc == undefined || doc == null)

        doc = frame.contentWindow.document;

    doc.open();

    doc.write(page);

    doc.close();
    doc.getElementById("uploadTarget").onload = uploadDone;

}
```

And the function executed on the "onload" is:

```
function uploadDone() {

    var frame = document.getElementById("uploadIFrame");

    var doc = frame.contentDocument;

    var innerFrame = doc.getElementById("uploadTarget");

    var ret = innerFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;

    var data = eval("(" + JSON.decode(ret) + ")"); 

    //var data = eval("("+ret+")"); 

    if (data=="0"){

        alert("<?php echo JText::_('ERROR_SAVE_IMAGE'); ?>");

    }

    else if (data=="") {

    }

    else {

        var upImage = new Element('img',{

            'class':'tutmainthumb',

            'id':'tutThumb',

            'src':'components/com_tutorial/helpers/image.php?img='+data

        });

        upImage.inject('tutImage','top');

        $('uploadIFrame').dispose();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reprhase this question on: [Joomla 2.5 ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769265/joomla-2-5-ajax-file-upload/)  go to that page to check the solution.